# Change boxplot legend's rectangles dimensions and legend text (Seaborn)

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'd like to change the text of the legend in a Seaborn `boxplot`, but when I do the little rectangles/icons that show the hue in the legend become really thin, so I'd like to control the dimension of these icons as well:

Before changing labels (default legend):

[image: Before]

After changing labels:

[image: After]

For reference, I'm changing labels using `ax.legend(labels = [....])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official reference example, the code to get the handler of the legend and add an arbitrary label name.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set3")
handler, label = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handler, [1,0])
```

[image]